# javax/el/ELUtil javax.el.ELManager.getExpressionFactory

Tags: java, jboss, bean-validation, jsr380

I am using Java Bean Validation jsr 380 that works perfectly in Tomcat,but in Jboss 6,i get this Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: javax/el/ELUtil
    javax.el.ELManager.getExpressionFactory
```

I added ressources below:

```
<resource-root path="javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar"/>
<resource-root path="javax.el-3.0.0.jar"/>
<resource-root path="classmate-1.3.1.jar"/>
<resource-root path="validation-api-2.0.0.Final.jar"/>
<resource-root path="hibernate-validator-6.0.0.Final.jar"/>
<resource-root path="jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR1.jar"/>
<resource-root path="hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-6.0.0.Final.jar"/>
```

The file jboss-deployment-structure is:

```
 <exclusions>
             ..................................
            <module name="javax.validation.api"/>  
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>
  </exclusions>
```

Thanks for help.